# Null value on SQL statement include the result of a SELECT query on the row (show the SQL query you sent and the result from that query)

Tags: c#, model-view-controller, asp.net-identity, dbcontext

I am working on a project , in order to use the Identity features in the last steps, I had to make some changes on database and add Identity to it. Also, inherit `DatabaContext` from `IdentityDbContext`. In my previous method I used to make a new object of `DatabaseContext` and work on it :

```
private DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
```

But with the new changes, when I pass the model to View or apply a conditional input, it returns a null value, for example, the following code:

```
 public JsonResult CheckUserNameAvailability(Int32 UserCode)
    {
      
        var SearchData = db.Persons.Where(p => p.Pcode == UserCode).FirstOrDefault();////this line
        
        if (SearchData != null)
        {
            TempData["code"] = 0;

            return Json(1);
        }
        else
        {
            TempData["code"] = UserCode;
            return Json(0);
        }
    }
```

**On the line**

var SearchData = db.Persons.Where (p => p.Pcode == UserCode) .FirstOrDefault();

**return Error**

> System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlNullValueException: 'Data is Null. This method or property cannot be called on Null values.

even though the database is not empty and this code used to work properly. If someone could provide some assistance, it would be terrific!

**and This is Model:**

```
namespace LeaveSheet.Models
{
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public Int32 Id { get; set; }
        public Int32 Pcode { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Family { get; set; }
     }
}
```

**codes in startup.cs**

```
 public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {        
        services.AddDbContext<DatabaseContext>(p => p.UseSqlServer(@"Data Source =. ; Initial Catalog = LeaveSheet; Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true "));          
        services.AddControllersWithViews();
        services.AddIdentity<User, Role>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<DatabaseContext>().AddDefaultTokenProviders();
    }
```

Comment: Can we see your model?

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the full error message including the full stacktrace. Also add the class of the `db.Persons` entity as well as the SQL `CREATE TABLE` statement of your table for that entity to your question.

Comment: yes sure -------

Comment: Try this `public Int32? Pcode { get; set; }` ?

Comment: @alirezanaseriMoghaddam Please [edit] your question to include the result of a `SELECT` query on the row you are trying to read (show the SQL query you sent and the result from that query).

Comment: Is definition for Pcode NOT NULL in db?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether the ID column in person table has always a value.

Even though it is the key column in model, check whether it is same in DB as well.

Comment: Yes the Id Value is OK,   also before this inheritance(DatabaseContext from IdnetityDbContext ) the codes where working and have been tested.

Comment: @aIireza, If you have upgraded any package references try to rollback them and see, sometimes some of the things  work in some older EF Core version without giving any issue even though with wrong mappings, but technically they shouldn't work. but in this latest versions of EF core, MS has fixed few issues such that. Check you DB and DBcontext for each and every tables,mappings. Earlier sometimes model fields with  [Required] mapping worked even though the data was not in the DB, now they are not working, I have experienced a slimier issue, Had to remove [Required]  from some of the fields.

Comment: I removed a **required** attribute for password and again code worked. Thanks Darshani